# Artifactory replication protocol

Tags: networking, protocols, artifactory, ports

I have searched JFrog support but was unable to find the particular protocol(s) and port(s) used by Artifactory to replicate contents to another Artifactory instance.  I want to make sure it will work with my intended network topology.

The scenario would involve 2 Artifactory instances replicating to each other across a firewall.  As such, I need to know the protocols and ports that are necessary for one to replicate to the other.

Can someone tell me the protocol(s) and port(s) used?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi Yisrael, your question is a bit confusing. Are you talking about HA topology of 2 nodes connected in the same cluster or do you mean two Artifactory instances replicating from one to another? those are two different scenarios, as the answer to the first one would be, as you are talking about HA topology, you might want to address JFrog support as this is an Enterprise level subscription which has 24/7 support by the EULA. 
If you mean the second option, replication please explain a bit more on the scenario so we might be able to assist.

Comment: I updated the description to be clearer.  Please let me know if you have the information needed or if there are other items I can clarify.  Thanks Ariel for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protocols are HTTP/HTTPS, depends on what you configured. All of the requests from Artifactory to the second instance will be using HTTP requests (GET, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, POST). The ports are the one you have configured your Artifactory to work with, the default is 8081.
Opening those will allow your Artifactory instances to communicate.

Comment: Ariel, thanks for getting back to me!  So that's including the files, metadata and repository structure?

Comment: Yes you will need to configure the repositories and replication, and Artifactory will take care of the rest

Comment: I tried to +1 your answer but apparently my newbie status prevented me.  Thank you Ariel for your help!

Comment: You, as the creator of the post, can mark the answer as the right one. So others will know that it helped you.

Comment: I marked it.  One other question (bonus round :) ):   Can the HTTP/HTTPS requests for transferring / replicating data be over UDP (as opposed to TCP)?  i.e., Can the transfer be configured to be HTTP over UDP?

Comment: Not that I know of... You might want to open a new question and let the community try to answer that :)